# How to format an in chrome Postman app?

Tags: php, arrays, postman

I have been sent a param called questionList.
The format is like this:-

```
'questionList' = [{"qid":"1","ans":"798789","qst_type":"text_area"},
 {"qid":"2","ans":"1","qst_type":"radio"},
 {"qid":"3","ans":"3","qst_type":"radio"},
 {"qid":"4","ans":"789789","qst_type":"text_area"},
 {"qid":"5","ans":"like","qst_type":"like_dislike"},
 {"qid":"6","ans":4,"qst_type":"rating"},
 {"qid":"7","ans":"2","qst_type":"smiley"}]
```

How can I parse the results as array?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving `JSON` formatted string. Use `json_decode($string, [$useAssoc])` to make it back to PHP array.

[Example code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6970aecbaa488a0c8f519e454889fae7ffda3d97)